# Evaluating mathematical expression in R

Tags: r, math

I have a vector containing mathematical expression as first index of the vector see below

```
(A+(B*C)/D)
```

where **A,B,C** and **D** are the field names of my data.table, I now want to add a new field(**result**) to my data.table which should be evaluated as per the expression contained in the vector(example provided above)

As a solution to it, I am looping  through each record and each field of the data table to calculate the value of the each row, which I think might not be the best solution in R, So wanted to check if there are any other possible solutions to my problem.

> > I don't want to use the base R operations like dt$A, dt$B and so on as it slows down the process
> >     Also my expression is a user input from shiny app so I cannot hardcode the field names

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You can make use of the `apply` family to get what you want

Comment: How about a classic `x$result <- (x$A+(x$B*x$C)/x$D)`?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot Two problems, 1) I don't want to use base R as it slows down the process 2) The expression is a user input(from a shiny app) so I cannot hardcode

Comment: OK, good to know, maybe you could edit your question to add this valuable piece of information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can evaluate the string within your data.table 's environment. As a quick example:

```
#parse the text first
express <- parse(text = 'A+(B*C)/D')

#dummy data 
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(A = runif(5),
                 B = runif(5),
                 C = runif(5),
                 D = runif(5))

#using eval
eval(express, envir = dt)
#[1] 0.2654480 0.6818451 0.7611150 5.5714248 2.8076066
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, however I noticed that the vector which contains the operation`(A+(B*C)/D)` to be performed is a character vector, which does not gives the expected result. Any pointer on how can i go around that ?

Comment: Updated the answer. That's why reproducible examples are always useful.